# Susy: Fluid grid based on maximum px values

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass, grid-layout

I am trying to make a fluid grid which at its maximum width has these values:

http://gridcalculator.dk/#/1224/12/40/56

When the browser is resized below 1264px (to allow for 20px padding on the body), everything (margins, gutters and columns) should scale down proportionally. Is this possible?

I have tried these approaches:

First try:

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 56px;
$gutter-width   : 40px;
$grid-padding   : 56px;
```

This doesn't work because the padding is fixed at 56px and doesn't scale down.

Second try:

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 4.575163%;
$gutter-width   : 3.267973%;
$grid-padding   : 4.575163%;

$container-width: 1224px;
```

This almost works but the grid padding is greater than the column width for some reason...

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use percentages or ems as your units instead of trying to scale your px values up/down depending on the resolution?  The reason your 2nd example has problems is because not every browser handles fractions of a pixel the same way, so you end up with rounding differences.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with rounding. The values I get for the padding are 1.5 times those for columns, even it the percentages I specify are the same.
I don't mind converting px to percentages too much, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of Susy? The whole point is "we do the maths for you". Designing a grid using px is much nicer that doing it with percents.

Comment: Why would that defeat the purpose of Suzy?  Does it have to do calculus level math for you *and* save the environment to justify using?  Clinging to the px unit is a touch irresponsible in my opinion, since it fails to take into account font-size adjustments users have made that you can do nothing about.  Ultimately, you're free to use whatever units you like, but "nicer" for you doesn't necessarily translate to "nicer" for the user.

Comment: Ok I understand. Sorry if I am a bit limited... I am just used to using px and this is my first try at responsive web design. However, using percentages doesn't really change anything in the problem I am having. I give the same values to column-width and grid-padding and they end up completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Susy 1.0 handles grid-padding differently from columns and gutters. In order to achieve what you are looking for, we would have to require special classes on both the first and last elements in a row. That is how Susy 0.9 worked, but it added a lot of complexity for a feature most people complained about. Now, with grid-padding added to the container rather than the elements, what you want is not possible.

The grid padding is now added directly to the container, without any math. In your first example, that means it doesn't flex. In your second example, it is interpreted by browsers as a percentage of the entire viewport, while gutters are a percentage of the container, thus resulting in different widths.